# aws instance enable SR-IOV issue

Tags: linux, aws, cloud

We have are running our own centOS on aws cloud to have more control on update and patch OS. but recently we have notice on our instance `m4.x2large` we don't have `SR-IOV` enabled so this is what i did

1. shutdown instance
2. run this command to enable 
   `aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id YOUR_INSTANCE_ID --sriov-net-support simple`
3. start instance

but i have noticed instance staying `running` but `status check` stuck on `Initializing` did i do something wrong?